# Creating a grid using for loops jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a 16x16 grid using jquery. I have a main div, and then I'm trying to create the grid within it. I am using for loops, but when the code below runs, I get a 16x32 grid.

Could anyone explain what is going on and why that is happening?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>etch-a-sketch</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</body>
```

```
#main {
   height: 192px;
   width: 192px;
   background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.squares {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   margin: 1px;
   background-color: aquamarine;
   display: inline-block;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   for(var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
       for(var y=0; y<16; y++) {
           $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo('#main');
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: it comes out 16x16 for me. Can you provide a JsFiddle ?

Comment: I ran it through [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcjcy1b1/1/) as well and got the same 16x16 grid. If you have additional code, that may be effecting your grid.

Comment: add `float: left;` to squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a 16x16 grid. When you're using "inline", spaces take place. Just change the CSS code to this:

```css
#main {
  height: 192px;
  width: 192px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.squares {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Note:

```css
display: block;
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your thought process was off.. I think the best way to make a 16x16 grid (256 boxes total) would be the way I went below and use css to style them.

The HTML

```
<div id="main">

</div>
```

The CSS

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
}
.squares {
  width:6%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The Javascript

```
for(var x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
    $("<div class='squares'>hi</div>").appendTo('#main');
}
```